# Loop though array and store values in another array

Tags: c#

Please check loop bellow. "BulkScannedItemIds" is an array with few ids which looping to retrieve those products and storing in "singleItems" But problem is "singleItems" is not an array. That's why its not holding all values. So What i want is store all value to a array. Please advice me how can i make this ("singleItems") simple variable to array? So it will able to hold all values after run the loop?

```
foreach (var BulkScannedItemId in BulkScannedItemIds)
{
    var singleItems = ctx.BulkScannedItems.Where(x => x.UserSellerScanRequestId == id && x.BulkScannedItemId == BulkScannedItemId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Just use `ToArray()` instead of `ToList()` for having an array.
And remove the foreach loop, it does nothing, beside slow your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without the loop using LINQ:

```
var singleItems = ctx.BulkScannedItems.Where(x => x.UserSellerScanRequestId == id && BulkScannedItemIds.Contains(x.BulkScannedItemId)).ToList()
```

**EDIT**: Or if you want an Array call ToArray instead:

```
var singleItems = ctx.BulkScannedItems.Where(x => x.UserSellerScanRequestId == id && BulkScannedItemIds.Contains(x.BulkScannedItemId)).ToArray()
```

Comment: Unless you call `.ToArray()` in which case it will be converted to an array... :O